# How to make a script to generate files and insert text from a percentage distribution?

Tags: perl, bash

I'm a true novice with bash/perl scripting but have to come up with a solution to this problem I have.

I need to generate files named after the english alphabet from `1 to 9`, `a to z` and `A to Z`.
So in total there will be 61 files.

After that I need to insert text to each file according to a pre-defined distribution, say:

```
text1 80%
text2 10%
text3 5%
text4 2%
text5 2%
text6 1%
```

When each file contains only one text and from the example there is a 80% chance that the file named `C` for instance will contain the text `text1`. Similarly, The file named `7` will have 5% chance to contain the text `text3`.

My question is where to start? what is preferred bash or perl? I think generating the files would be somewhat easy but echoing text to files according to a distribution will be tricky.

This is where I'm at using bash:

Create files and enter same text:

```
for f in {a..z} {A..Z} {1..9}
do
    echo text > "$f"
done
```

**EDIT:** It's under ubuntu 10.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the files is trivial in bash, filling them isn't quite so clean but isn't all that bad:

```
for file in {1..9} {a..z} {A..Z}; do 
    (
    line=$((RANDOM % 100))
    if (( line < 80 )); then 
        echo text1
    elif (( line < 90 )); then 
        echo text2
    elif (( line < 95 )); then 
        echo text3
    [...]
    fi
    ) >$file
done
```

`$RANDOM` isn't a great source of randomness, but it's probably fine for this.

Comment: @Tom you mean you only want one of the lines, not independent probabilities?

Comment: just to be sure, `text2` will apeear 18% of time?

Comment: Text2 will appear 10% of the time, as you stated in the question. If you want other numbers, it's easy enough to swap them in, it's just a standard random selection algorithm.

Comment: the probabilty is to not get `text1` = 0.2 times getting `text2`= 0.9 equals 18%

Answer (score 1):

This Perl program does what you ask.

It first takes the text as you have shown in your question and pairs it up as text/percentage pairs in an array. This data is used by subroutine `gentext` to produce a random string at the rates given.

Then all there is to do is to run the loop that creates the files and enters a random string into each.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @rates = map [ /(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*)\s+(\d+)%?\s*$/ ], split /\n/, <<END;
  text1 80%
  text2 10%
  text3 5%
  text4 2%
  text5 2%
  text6 1%
END

for my $file ('a' .. 'z', 'A' .. 'Z', '0' .. '9') {
  open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
  print $fh gentext(), "\n";
}

sub gentext {
  my $rn = rand() * 100;
  for (@rates) {
    $rn -= $_->[1];
    return $_->[0] if $rn < 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your question right. But I think what you are searching for is a basic randomnumber generator. Maybe this could help you:
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html

Good Luck

Comment: I'm trying to generate files under Ubuntu and insert text to them.